# Xamarin.Forms Page doesn't detect OnBackButtonPressed event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

i have a ContentPage that somewhy doesn't detect the hardware back button press, even though some other pages I created do detect it.

Anyone had issues like this before ?

I inserted a breakpoint on OnBackButtonPressed event and it doesn't ever run that code.
The event OnAppearing does fire, so i'm successfully navigating to that page..

```
public class ProductsPage: BaseMobilityPage
{
    private readonly ProductsViewModel _viewModel;

    public ProductsPage()
    {
        Title = AppResources.AddNewProductTitle;
        _viewModel = ((ViewModelLocator)Application.Current.Resources[Constants.LocatorKey]).ProductsViewModel;

        BindingContext = _viewModel;
        BackgroundColor = _viewModel.StyleConfig.GrayColor;

        var root = GeneralCode.DefineListUi(_viewModel.NavigateToSelectItem, new DataTemplate(typeof(ProductCell)));

        Content = root;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await _viewModel.GetProductsAsync();
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work. Try to create an new project and check it there. Perhaps the problem is in your working project.

Comment: It does work fine. Not seen any bug or issue around it.